# Searching for new tweets on Twitter using RTweet's search_tweets() function

Tags: r, twitter, rtweet

I am switching from using `twitteR` to `Rtweet` to automatically search Twitter for new tweets (`twitteR` seems to truncate the text at 140 characters).The `searchTwitter()` function in the twitteR package contained a `sinceID` argument that allowed me to easily search for only the newest tweets and append them to my existing dataset. I cannot find a similar function in the `search_tweets()` function of the `Rtweet` package. Is there any way to avoid having to download the entire corpus of tweets and then delete duplicates, and instead only download the newest tweets?

Here is the function and an example of what I currently use:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidytext)
library(twitteR)

# FUNCTION ----------
searchtwitterlastweek_ft <- function(topic, sinceID){
  today <- as.character(Sys.Date())
  lastweek <- as.character(Sys.Date() - 6)
  searchtwitterfortopic <- searchTwitteR(topic, n = 15000, since = lastweek, until = today, sinceID = sinceID)
  if(!length(searchtwitterfortopic) == 0){
    twListToDF(searchtwitterfortopic)
  } else {
    data.frame(list())
  }
}

# LOAD DATASET FROM PREVIOUS WEEKS ---------
load("DATA/rstats.Rda")

df_r <- df_r %>%
  arrange(desc(id))

# figure out last ID, i.e. last tweet on subject
lastid <- first(df_r$id)

df_temporary <- searchtwitterlastweek_ft("#rstats", lastid)

df_r <- rbind(df_r, df_temporary) %>%
  arrange(desc(id))
```

Comment: so you're not "scraping", you're just running a scheduled search on the API.

Comment: Thanks for flagging this, I tweaked the question to make this clearer.

Answer (score 0):

look at the stream_tweet function of the rtweet pack that should help you =)